# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object

Tags: javascript, php

So I am trying to change up my url path to match the name of my SQL tables.

I have an html page that follows a form, after the user clicks Create it runs the following JS code:

```
if (form.EventID.value && confirm("Are you sure you want to create: " + form.EventID.value + "?")) {
        form.action = '/srv/events/create';
    }
```

Which in theory should link to the following php statement:

```
$app->post('/events/create', function () {

    $args = $_POST;

    CreateSQL('events', $args, DefineEventFields());

});
```

What was before was '/event/create' and it worked with no problems, all I did was ann an 's' to the end of event and now it throws me these errors:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: app in ...
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function post() on a non-object in ...

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you bother READING the error message? "non-object" -> your $app isn't an object.

Comment: if it worked without the s then why did you add it?

Comment: I think there is crucial code we're not seeing here: the error message complains that $app is not set, and we don't see where you are expecting that to come from. Is this a standard framework?

Comment: $app was set just fine, the file name was just the same as the url path specified by crud so it ignored my main php file where I predefined my variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

`Call to a member function post() on a non-object`

You are calling the member function `post()` on a non-object: `$app`

You have to find out why `$app` has not been initialized.

Comment: The problem was that my file name matched the name of the path specified by crud. $app was defined in my main php file, after I changed the route it was no longer getting the contents of predefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your form action points to '/srv/events/create' change it to '/events/create'

Comment: the issue has been resolved, but that would make it worse since then it would ignore all of the php written in the /srv/ thats controlled through crud